# ncurses for Mac does not display color

Tags: ncurses

Mac ncurses is not able to display color

I ported a really old ncurses program (that I wrote a couple decades ago) from Win to Mac just by editing the Makefile to use the Mac library (libncursesw.a), and the program runs fine, but only in black and white, whereas the original Windows version was able to display colored text.

During initialization, the program runs:

```
    // prints "ncurses 6.4.20221231"
    printf("curses_version() = %s\n", curses_version());

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    nonl();
    raw();
    if(has_colors()) {
        start_color();
        init_pair(BRIGHT_YELLOW_TEXT, COLOR_YELLOW | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, COLOR_BLACK);
        /* More similar init_pair() initialization */
        attrset(COLOR_PAIR(WHITE_TEXT));
    }

    /* Test drawing yellow text prints WHITE_TEXT */
    attrset(COLOR_PAIR(BRIGHT_YELLOW_TEXT));
    mvprintw(1, 1, "TEST");
```

More details:

- Running on MacBook Pro 14-inch 2023
- Makefile links "libncursesw.a"
- ncurses version is 6.4
- has_colors() and can_change_color() both return true.

```
% printenv | grep TERM
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM=xterm-256color
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=447
TERM_SESSION_ID=13A85223-53F1-4C9C-B6A9-D0A17518DC51
```

Also note, my MacBook came with /usr/share/terminfo/41/Apple_Terminal, a binary which contains the string: "Apple_Terminal|AppKit Terminal.app v41+ w/MacRoman charset (color)"

So not sure where to look next

Comment: The example is [incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks -- updated sample with more code showing how the app draws colored text.   Note, the actual code of the app was never changed from it's original working state; just re-compiled on my MacBook, so I think it's a system issue.

Comment: Still incomplete. I filled in what you left out, and the result worked for me on my Mac, so... it would really benefit you to post a *complete* example that actually shows the problem (at least on your system).